# Flash builder - Possible to compile directly to device with free Apple account?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I normally develop using Flash Builder 4.7. Up until recently I have been a paying Apple Developer to test out my AS3 experiments on my mobile devices directly through Flash builder.

I just learned that you as a non-paying user can compile your Xcode projects directly to devices with a 7-day provisioning profile.

Is this approach also available for people using Flex / Flash Builder / Flashdevelop etc? My subscription recently ran out and if there is a free option I would prefer it as I'm only developing for my own fun.

Comment: Do any of these [**articles / tutorials**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=adobe+air+ios+%22provisioning+profile%22) in Google results make sense to your situation? The AIR sdk is what packages your app so focus on researching about AIR + iOS provisioning profile then apply logic to Flash Builder (settings etc)...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the provisioning file is required during the build phase, so simply create a new one then use the new provisioning file during export.

Apple does not know by what method you created a valid ipa file.

Comment: Allright, but where do I create the provisioning file? I used to do it at developer.apple.com but as a non paying member I cant create apps or access the provisioning portal. Can I do it through XCode?

Comment: I believe you need to create a normal apple account, then in Xcode >Preferences—->Accounts create a new identity. I do not know a way to generate the provisioning file outside of xcode.